# errorexception mkdir(): Permission Denied Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter

When I try to upload a file into the server's Public directory using bellow code

```
if($this->request->getMethod()=='post'){
$file = $this->request->getFile('file');
  if($file->isValid() && !$file->hasMoved()){
   if( $file->move(ROOTPATH.'public/upload/img')){echo "Uploaded";}
   else{ echo "Failed"; }
```

errorexception mkdir(): Permission Denied Error Message comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subdirectory under the public directory as upload and then change the permission 775 to 777